# dhclient error "Bind socket to interface: No such device"

Tags: debian, dhclient

I experienced a strange error. If I tried to connect to the internet via WiFi, everything went well except the DHCP transaction. `dhclient` prints this error message `Bind socket to interface: No such device`
Switched to static IP (set in the client e.g. Wicd) and killed the `dhclient` process => Connection is established without issues. There are no further errors beside said `dhclient` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice coincidence, i just stumbled over this problem here tonight.
My "problem" are unique device names, my wifi dongle is renamed from wlan0 to wlx112233445566 (with the mac address).  This device name seems to be too long for dhclient.  (Now that's robust coding, is it?)

If i keep the kernel from renaming the wifi device (by udev rule), dhclient is happy with the device name wlan0 and this strange error disappears.

Comment: Exactly the solution! Who would expect dhclient to be coded that bad, so their buffer for the interface name would overflow. Big thank you!

Comment: Update: Bug in the Debian Bug Tracker is filed